# How does Laravel know that instance of the Request class contains the request currently being made by the user?

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning about dependency Injection in PHP,
When I call this function in my Controller,

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $value = $request->session()->get('key');


    }
```

it works, but how does Laravel know that the Request class being injected contains the current request made by the user, or a new instance of the Request class?

Comment: It's to do with service providers and containers. The docs explains it pretty well: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#automatic-injection

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `public/index.php`, you can see Laravel create the initial `$request` object by capturing the global request values.

```
// public/index.php ln 53
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
```

The request is then passed to the `Http\Kernel` for handling, where the `$request` is subsequently passed to the `sendRequestThroughRouter()` function.  In this function, the request instance is bound to the application container.

```
// vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php ln 138
$this->app->instance('request', $request);
```

Now, every time the application injects a request instance, for example into your controller method, it knows specifically which object to use.

Comment: This tells 90% of the story, however there's still one step between the string `request` and being able to inject it as a dependency using the class name. When the `Application` class (in other words the primary service container in Laravel) is being spun up, it calls [registerCoreContainerAliases()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1122). This means that if you bind something to `request` like is done in the Kernel, it will also resolve for `Illuminate\Http\Request` and `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`.

Comment: To expand a bit further....when the Controller method is building its type-hinted dependencies, it will come across `Illuminate\Http\Request` and throw that to the `Application`/`Container`. The container's [resolve() will check to see if it's an alias](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L587) of something using the [`getAlias()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L1041) method. That will respond with the `request` string and from there on out it's just normal service resolution.